# Weights of a faithful representation and roots of $\mathfrak{g}$

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras, root-systems, semisimple-lie-algebras

I fail to understand an elementary statement about roots  of a semisimple Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ and weights of a faithful representation.

There are two sources for the classification of simple Lie superalgebras: The article "Lie superalgebras" by Kac and the book "The theory of Lie superalgebras - an introduction"
by Scheunert. The following assertion occurs in the article by Kac (Proof of Lemma 1.4.1) and the book by Scheunert (Proof of lemma 2 in the appendix):

> Let $\rho$ be a finite-dimensional irreducible faithful representation
> of a semisimple Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$. Let $\lambda$ be the
> highest weight of $\rho$ and $\mu$ the lowest weight. Then $2\lambda$
> or $\lambda - \mu$ can only be roots of $\mathfrak{g}$ if
> $\mathfrak{g}$ is simple.

Kac doesn't give any arguments. Scheunert writes:

> "It is well-known that $-\mu$ is the highest weight of the
> representation contragredient to $\rho$; in particular $-\mu$ is
> dominant. Recalling that $\rho$ is faithful we conclude that
> $2\lambda$ or $\lambda - \mu$ can be a root of $\mathfrak{g}$ only if
> $\mathfrak{g}$ is simple".

I agree that $-\mu$ is dominant, but why does this imply the claim?

Comment: Yes, just finite-dimensional semisimple Lie algebras.